# Using React-Dom's render more than once

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Is it at all possible to use `react-dom`'s render more than once in a react spa, in particular in a nested child component? For example:

**index.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import sampleComponent from './sampleComponent';

render(<SampleComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**sampleComponent.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const SampleComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <div id="foo" />
  </div>
);

export default SampleComponent;


render(<h1>it's me again</h1>, document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Comment: You need to tell for which reason you need to render a single component more than once, because the question seems weird in my opinion. If its properties does not change, there is no reason it should render again.

Comment: If you create a key that always changes, `<SampleComponent key={Math.random()}/>` it should continually update. But the real question is what you want to accomplish, becuase there are surely better ways to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

To use render more than once is a complicated way.
You don't need that.

You already create a valid component. Just wrap it into another and use more then once. En example:

```
const SampleComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <div id="foo" />
  </div>
);

const WrapperComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <SampleComponent />
    <SampleComponent />
  </div>
);

export default WrapperComponent;
```

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to render more than once, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can get a ref to a dom node and use ReactDOM.render() on it. I don't know why you would do that. There is almost certainly a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @Jimmy It is possible but you rarely would do that. You usually you want all of your components to share the same component tree especially in a SPA. There are a few edge cases where you want to render components outside of the root element. For that you should use [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) instead. Usually those components will render modals and overlays that need to break out of the layout.

Comment: I've never used render more then once in my solid  practice with React. If you do it, it'll be anti pattern of React philosophy. The best way is to reuse a components with different props if it need.

Comment: @Jackkobec This doesn't prevent you from reusing components. They just do not share a common parent. There are valid use cases for that e.g. if you are using widget-like components in an otherwise statically generated page.

Comment: @Jackkobec Say you have a statically generated page with whatever content that is not interactive at all. But in a sidebar you want a weather widget and in the footer you want an interactive map. Both of these widgets are in separate parts of the DOM and do not share any context. You could write those widgets with react and render them into their totally separate DOM nodes. But this would certainly not qualify as a single page application.

Comment: Thank you. It is very specific, but possible.